# MySQL query slow with order by + group by

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which is performing slowly since the addition of the `ORDER BY` clause. It seems to be some issue with the combination of `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` but I'm unsure where to start with optimization. The groups table has about 100k rows currently, and all the id's used in the joins are indexed.

```
SELECT groups.name,groups.account_id,groups.description,groups.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name) as cat, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT group_tags.name) as tag
FROM groups 
LEFT JOIN group_categories ON groups.id = group_categories.group_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON group_categories.cat_id = categories.id
LEFT JOIN group_tags ON groups.id = group_tags.group_id
GROUP BY groups.id
ORDER BY case when groups.account_id = 0 then 1 else 0 end, groups.name
```

**EXPLAIN output:**

```
SIMPLE  groups              index   NULL        PRIMARY     4    NULL                       100843  Using temporary; Using filesort
SIMPLE  group_categories    ref     group_id    group_id    4    groups.id                  1   
SIMPLE  categories          eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4    group_categories.cat_id    1
```

**CREATE TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `accountid` (`account_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=109850 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: look at "Using temporary; Using filesort": this means that the whole result set is fetched and then sorted before it starts being sent.

Comment: The culprit is `ORDER BY CASE` which cannot be indexed in mySQL

Comment: Try `ORDER BY (groups.account_id = 0)`. not sure it helps but it could, and it's shorter.

Comment: @JanDvorak Unfortunately even if I change that to a simple `ORDER BY groups.name` it still performs badly, so while removing the case does get rid of the filesort it doesn't speed it up :-)

Comment: Then it most likely lacks a different index. What does EXPLAIN say when you do `ORDER BY groups.name`?

Comment: `SIMPLE groups index NULL name 767 NULL 10 Using temporary`

Comment: How are you doing the timing?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just executing the raw query through a MySQL admin app (Sequel Pro) and adding SQL_NO_CACHE to the query, but also through the website the performance is visibly slow when ordered.

Comment: @Tom . . . If you add the order by conditions into the `group by`, does that help the performance?  I think the query would be semantically the same.